# Is it possible to limit size of the AWS Cognito token?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

Is it possible to limit size of the AWS Cognito token?

I mean token from https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito-user-identity-pools/latest/APIReference/API_InitiateAuth.html

I found https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/user-pool-lambda-pre-token-generation.html

but didn't see options to limit size of token